# How to synchronize only timestamps with WinSCP?

Tags: command-line, timestamp, winscp

I am trying to update only timestamps with WinSCP. I can't find many examples online so I am asking here.

```
synchronize timestamps -filemask=" | *.txt; *.log" "source" "target"
```

I have tried this command, but I keep getting an 'unknown option' message. I have tried `-timestamps` and variations of this with no luck.

[Documentation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_synchronize_full) doesn't have any examples. It mentions it can only work with SFTP so I am unsure if there is another parameter or switch to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [timestamp synchronization](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_synchronize_full#mode) functionality is not directly available in WinSCP scripting.

But you can set raw configuration option [`Interface\SynchronizeParams`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawconfig#interface_synchronizeparams) using [`/rawconfig` command-line parameter](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#configuration):

```
winscp.com /script=yourscript.txt /ini=nul /rawconfig Interface\SynchronizeParams=256
```

Then the following command will update remote *timestamps*, instead of remote *files*:

```
synchronize remote -filemask=" | *.txt; *.log" "source" "target"
```

(analogically for `local`)